# Node reading file in specified chunk size

Tags: node.js, upload, amazon-glacier

The goal: Upload large files to AWS Glacier without holding the whole file in memory.

I'm currently uploading to glacier now using fs.readFileSync() and things are working. But, I need to handle files larger than 4GB and I'd like to upload multiple chunks in parallel. This means moving to multipart uploads.
I can choose the chunk size but then glacier needs every chunk to be the same size (except the last)

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/p5FuU1oxbeY) thread suggests that I can set a chunk size on a read stream but that I'm not actually guaranteed to get it.

Any info on how I can get consistent parts without reading the whole file into memory and splitting it up manually?

Assuming I can get to that point I was just going to use cluster with a few processes pulling off the stream as fast as they can upload to AWS.
If that seems like the wrong way to parallelize the work I'd love suggestions there.

Answer (score 30):

If nothing else you can just use [`fs.open()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback), [`fs.read()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback), and [`fs.close()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) manually. Example:

```
var CHUNK_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10MB
    buffer = Buffer.alloc(CHUNK_SIZE),
    filePath = '/tmp/foo';

fs.open(filePath, 'r', function(err, fd) {
  if (err) throw err;
  function readNextChunk() {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE, null, function(err, nread) {
      if (err) throw err;

      if (nread === 0) {
        // done reading file, do any necessary finalization steps

        fs.close(fd, function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
        return;
      }

      var data;
      if (nread < CHUNK_SIZE)
        data = buffer.slice(0, nread);
      else
        data = buffer;

      // do something with `data`, then call `readNextChunk();`
    });
  }
  readNextChunk();
});
```

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, using a regular file descriptor forgoes all of the stream event goodness which is really useful when you are trying to read/write a file in an async code base.

Comment: Running this code today causes the following warning:

"(node:25440) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead."

Comment: @theycallmemorty This answer was from well before it was deprecated. I've updated it now for modern versions of node.

Comment: You may prefer createReadStream solution which is more readable

Comment: @Poyoman This solution is the only way to _guarantee_ chunk sizes, which is what the OP asked for. If you don't need specific chunk sizes, then yes, streaming is much easier.

Comment: I would suggest replacing the buffer. slice to buffer.subarray , https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end

I had trouble reading some pdf files with the above approach.

Answer (score 14):

You may consider using below snippet where we read file in chunk of 1024 bytes

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = '';

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/foo.txt',{ highWaterMark: 1 * 1024, encoding: 'utf8' });

readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
    console.log('chunk Data : ')
    console.log(chunk);// your processing chunk logic will go here

}).on('end', function() {
    console.log('###################');
    console.log(data); 
// here you see all data processed at end of file
    });
```

Please Note : highWaterMark is the parameter used for chunk size
Hope this Helps!

Web Reference: https://stackabuse.com/read-files-with-node-js/ [Changing readstream chunksize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641571/changing-readstream-chunksize)

Comment: Finally a good example of Node streams that doesn't look like way too abstract nonsense and doesn't bore me explaining what binary numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [mscdex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111078/340997) here's a module using the sync alternative and with a StringDecoder to correctly parse UTF-8

The problem with `readableStream` is that in order to use it, you've to convert the entire project to use async emitters & callbacks. If you're coding something simple, like a small CLI in nodejs, it doesn't make sense.

```
//usage
let file = new UTF8FileReader()
file.open('./myfile.txt', 1024) 
while ( file.isOpen ) {
    let stringData=file.readChunk()
    console.log(stringData)
}


//--------------------
// UTF8FileReader.ts
//--------------------
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { StringDecoder, NodeStringDecoder } from "string_decoder";

export class UTF8FileReader {

    filename: string;
    isOpen: boolean = false;
    private chunkSize: number;
    private fd: number; //file handle from fs.OpenFileSync
    private readFilePos: number;
    private readBuffer: Buffer;

    private utf8decoder: NodeStringDecoder

    /**
     * open the file | throw
     * @param filename
     */
    open(filename, chunkSize: number = 16 * 1024) {

        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;

        try {
            this.fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'r');
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw new Error("opening " + filename + ", error:" + e.toString());
        }

        this.filename = filename;
        this.isOpen = true;

        this.readBuffer = Buffer.alloc(this.chunkSize);
        this.readFilePos = 0;

        //a StringDecoder is a buffered object that ensures complete UTF-8 multibyte decoding from a byte buffer
        this.utf8decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8')

    }

    /**
     * read another chunk from the file 
     * return the decoded UTF8 into a string
     * (or throw)
     * */
    readChunk(): string {

        let decodedString = '' //return '' by default

        if (!this.isOpen) {
            return decodedString;
        }

        let readByteCount: number;
        try {
            readByteCount = fs.readSync(this.fd, this.readBuffer, 0, this.chunkSize, this.readFilePos);
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw new Error("reading " + this.filename + ", error:" + e.toString());
        }

        if (readByteCount) {
            //some data read, advance readFilePos 
            this.readFilePos += readByteCount;
            //get only the read bytes (if we reached the end of the file)
            const onlyReadBytesBuf = this.readBuffer.slice(0, readByteCount);
            //correctly decode as utf8, and store in decodedString
            //yes, the api is called "write", but it decodes a string - it's a write-decode-and-return the string kind-of-thing :)
            decodedString = this.utf8decoder.write(onlyReadBytesBuf); 
        }
        else {
            //read returns 0 => all bytes read
            this.close();
        }
        return decodedString 
    }

    close() {
        if (!this.isOpen) {
            return;
        }
        fs.closeSync(this.fd);
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.utf8decoder.end();
    }

}
```

and here is the .js transpiled code if you don't have typescript yet:

```
// UTF8FileReader.js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.UTF8FileReader = void 0;
//--------------------
// UTF8FileReader
//--------------------
const fs = require("fs");
const string_decoder_1 = require("string_decoder");
class UTF8FileReader {
    constructor() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
    /**
     * open the file | throw
     * @param filename
     */
    open(filename, chunkSize = 16 * 1024) {
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        try {
            this.fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'r');
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw new Error("opening " + filename + ", error:" + e.toString());
        }
        this.filename = filename;
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.readBuffer = Buffer.alloc(this.chunkSize);
        this.readFilePos = 0;
        //a StringDecoder is a buffered object that ensures complete UTF-8 multibyte decoding from a byte buffer
        this.utf8decoder = new string_decoder_1.StringDecoder('utf8');
    }
    /**
     * read another chunk from the file
     * return the decoded UTF8 into a string
     * (or throw)
     * */
    readChunk() {
        let decodedString = ''; //return '' by default
        if (!this.isOpen) {
            return decodedString;
        }
        let readByteCount;
        try {
            readByteCount = fs.readSync(this.fd, this.readBuffer, 0, this.chunkSize, this.readFilePos);
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw new Error("reading " + this.filename + ", error:" + e.toString());
        }
        if (readByteCount) {
            //some data read, advance readFilePos 
            this.readFilePos += readByteCount;
            //get only the read bytes (if we reached the end of the file)
            const onlyReadBytesBuf = this.readBuffer.slice(0, readByteCount);
            //correctly decode as utf8, and store in decodedString
            //yes, the api is called "write", but it decodes a string - it's a write-decode-and-return the string kind-of-thing :)
            decodedString = this.utf8decoder.write(onlyReadBytesBuf);
        }
        else {
            //read returns 0 => all bytes read
            this.close();
        }
        return decodedString;
    }
    close() {
        if (!this.isOpen) {
            return;
        }
        fs.closeSync(this.fd);
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.utf8decoder.end();
    }
}
exports.UTF8FileReader = UTF8FileReader;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/read-chunk/blob/main/index.js), as `buffer.slice` is deprecated and for me, it had issues while reading big pdf files.

```
import {promisify} from 'node:util';
import fs from 'node:fs';
import {Buffer} from 'node:buffer';
import pify from 'pify';

const fsReadP = pify(fs.read, {multiArgs: true});
const fsOpenP = promisify(fs.open);
const fsCloseP = promisify(fs.close);

export async function readChunk(filePath, {length, startPosition}) {
    const fileDescriptor = await fsOpenP(filePath, 'r');

    try {
        let [bytesRead, buffer] = await fsReadP(fileDescriptor, {
            buffer: Buffer.alloc(length),
            length,
            position: startPosition,
        });

        if (bytesRead < length) {
            buffer = buffer.subarray(0, bytesRead);
        }

        return buffer;
    } finally {
        await fsCloseP(fileDescriptor);
    }
}

export function readChunkSync(filePath, {length, startPosition}) {
    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(length);
    const fileDescriptor = fs.openSync(filePath, 'r');

    try {
        const bytesRead = fs.readSync(fileDescriptor, buffer, {
            length,
            position: startPosition,
        });

        if (bytesRead < length) {
            buffer = buffer.subarray(0, bytesRead);
        }

        return buffer;
    } finally {
        fs.closeSync(fileDescriptor);
    }
}
```