# Changing readstream chunksize

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a socket based filetransfer system and because of that I came up with some trouble. I want to read files in chunks using node's fs.createReadStream() but I was unable to change the chunk size from 665536. I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: Could you help with a related question: In this situation (socket-based filesharing), what's an ideal chunk size? And in general (aside from sockets), what's an ideal chunk size?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

According to the [ReadStream code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/523929c9272a53c9429616564a45f2af59670e47/lib/fs.js#L1461-L1463), you should be able to increase the `highWaterMark` by explicitly setting it in the ReadStream options:

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar', { highWaterMark: 128 * 1024 });
```

Comment: @mscdex This was a super helpful answer, how on earth would you know that was there? :-)

Comment: @KarlBateman I was already familiar with the code base, but the docs (at least currently) hint at it.

Comment: @mscdex Well I salute you, that saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: 'bufferSize' would be the better name for 'highWaterMark' in my opinion

Comment: here's the param in docs, if anyone's interested https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options

Comment: @mscdex What is an ideal (safe and fast) size?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you are going to change the change the size of the chunk with highWaterMark : 8 , you can set it to 8,16,24 all are in bytes, be sure if you make chunk size to much high then you are by passing the benefit of using readerstream1. Because benefit of readerstream or stream is that they work efficiently while consuming less memory.

```
let readerstream1 = fs.createReadStream('shamoon.txt', { highWaterMark: 8 });
```