# Is there a more elegant way to read then write *the same file* with node js stream

Tags: node.js

I wanna read file then change it with `through2` then write into the same file, code like:

```
const rm = require('rimraf')
const through2 = require('through2')
const fs = require('graceful-fs')
// source file path
const replacementPath = `./static/projects/${destPath}/index.html`
// temp file path
const tempfilePath = `./static/projects/${destPath}/tempfile.html`
// read source file then write into temp file
await promiseReplace(replacementPath, tempfilePath)    
// del the source file
rm.sync(replacementPath)
// rename the temp file name to source file name
fs.renameSync(tempfilePath, replacementPath)
// del the temp file
rm.sync(tempfilePath)

// promiseify readStream and writeStream
function promiseReplace (readfile, writefile) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.createReadStream(readfile)
      .pipe(through2.obj(function (chunk, encoding, done) {
        const replaced = chunk.toString().replace(/id="wrap"/g, 'dududud')
        done(null, replaced)
      }))
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(writefile))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log('replace done')
        res()
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
        rej(err)
      })
  })
}
```

the above code works, but I wanna know can I make it more elegant ?

and I also try some temp lib like [node-temp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/temp)

unfortunately， it cannot readStream and writeStream into the same file as well, and I open [a issues](https://github.com/bruce/node-temp/issues/66) about this.

So any one know a better way to do this tell me, thank you very much.

Comment: [Stream transforms](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) were invented to make this more elegant.

Comment: I think `through2` is like node.js transforms, @jfriend00

Comment: This looks dangerous. How can you be sure that `id="wrap"` won't be split on a chunk edge?

Comment: @PitaJ Because I use `toString` method first, then replace it, but it's not the point, I wanna know a better way to do this, I do not like temp files.

Comment: No, that's not a true solution. Let's say you have a file like this: `lorem ipsum dolar sit <span id="wrap">something else</span>`. The way streams work is that the whole file is split into chunks of data. Through2's callback executes on each chunk separately. Your naive solution will fail if the file is split to `lorem ipsum dolar sit <span id="` and `wrap">something else</span>`

Comment: So you say the `fs.createReadStream(readfile)` will not make the whole file is split into chunks of data? why? and how to make chunks of data is whole file? and for now above code works.

Comment: The stream _will_ be split into chunks. @PitaJ means that it is difficult to know _where_ the chunk boundaries are (i.e. exactly how many chunks there are, how big they are, etc). Think of it like cutting an apple, you may not end up with the same number of pieces, even if you could "retry" with the same apple, let alone with different apples. The pieces won't be the same size or from the same places. So, I cannot `chunk.replace('apple', 'banana')` because `chunk` might start with `apple` or `pple` or `ple` or `le` or `e`. And it will only work if it happens to be the first case.

Comment: So how to avoid this risk? For now the replacement file which is xxx.html is I written, so I can control the file every time, but I do not know how to control the chunk boundaries? I thought whatever chunks change, then  the `toString()` will restore it, maybe I'm wrong,  so should I use non-stream `fs.readFile()` API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make the code more elegant by getting rid of unnecessary dependencies and using the newer simplified constructor for streams.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const tempWrite = require('temp-write');

const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename);

const goat2llama = async (filePath) => {
    const str = fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8')
        .pipe(new stream.Transform({
            decodeStrings : false,
            transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
                done(null, chunk.replace(/goat/g, 'llama'));
            }
        }));
    const tempPath = await tempWrite(str);
    await rename(tempPath, filePath);
};
```

### Tests

[AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava) tests to prove that it works:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import util from 'util';
import test from 'ava';
import mkdirtemp from 'mkdirtemp';
import goat2llama from '.';

const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const fixture = async (content) => {
    const dir = await mkdirtemp();
    const fixturePath = path.join(dir, 'fixture.txt');
    await writeFile(fixturePath, content);
    return fixturePath;
};

test('goat2llama()', async (t) => {
    const filePath = await fixture('I like goats and frogs, but goats the best');
    await goat2llama(filePath);
    t.is(await readFile(filePath, 'utf8'), 'I like llamas and frogs, but llamas the best');
});
```

A few things about the changes:

- Through2 is not really needed anymore. It used to be a pain to set up passthrough or transform streams properly, but that is not the case anymore thanks to the [simplified construction](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_simplified_construction) API.
- You probably don't need graceful-fs, either. Unless you are doing a lot of concurrent disk I/O, `EMFILE` is not usually a problem, especially these days as Node has gotten smarter about file descriptors. But that library does help with temporary errors caused by antivirus software on Windows, if that is a problem for you.
- You definitely do not need rimraf for this. You only need [`fs.rename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback). It is similar to [`mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) on the command line, with a few nuances that make it distinct, but the differences are not super important here. The point is there will be nothing at the temporary path after you rename the file that was there.
- I used [temp-write](https://github.com/sindresorhus/temp-write) because it generates a secure random filepath for you and puts it in the OS temp directory (which automatically gets cleaned up now and then), plus it handles converting the stream to a `Promise` for you and takes care of some edge cases around errors. **Disclosure:** I wrote the streams implementation in `temp-write`. :)

Overall, this is a decent improvement. However, there remains the [boundary problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483326/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-read-then-write-the-same-file-with-node-js-stre#comment79997445_46483326) discussed in the comments. Luckily, you are not the first person to encounter this problem! I wouldn't call the [actual solution](https://github.com/eugeneware/replacestream/blob/8517483759761dff23a1f5379f5d7522ea7bef60/index.js#L30-L60) particularly elegant, certainly not if you implement it yourself. But [replacestream](https://github.com/eugeneware/replacestream) is here to help you.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const tempWrite = require('temp-write');
const replaceStream = require('replacestream');

const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename);

const goat2llama = async (filePath) => {
    const str = fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8')
        .pipe(replaceStream('goat', 'llama'));
    const tempPath = await tempWrite(str);
    await rename(tempPath, filePath);
};
```

Also...

> I do not like temp files

Indeed, temp files are often bad. However, in this case, the temp file is managed by a well-designed library and stored in a secure, out-of-the-way location. There is virtually no chance of conflicting with other processes. And even if the `rename()` fails somehow, the file will be cleaned up by the OS.

That said, you can avoid temp files altogether by using [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) and [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) instead of streaming. The former also makes text replacement much easier since you do not have to worry about chunk boundaries. You have to choose one approach or the other, however for very big files, streaming may be the only option, aside from [manually chunking the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111078/2990144).

Comment: So can I say if I use `replacestream`, I can never worry about boundary problem any more ?

Comment: Yes, it is what `replacestream` is designed to do. Basically, it buffers the stream enough to ensure that you can match across multiple chunks.

Comment: Hmm... About that tempWrite - I assume it won't make sure it does the write on the same fs?

Comment: @MichałKapracki are you asking if `temp-write` supports writing across disk partitions and things like that? If so, then yes, it should work.

Comment: What I'm asking is that if you want to do the above on a partition different than the one in `/tmp` then the file will get saved and copied, not moved. But actually I checked that module and you can add a path to the temp file there - something may be worth adding to you answer...

Answer (score 2):

Streams are useless in this situation, because they return you chunks of file that can break the string that you're searching for. You could use streams, then merge all these chunks to get content, then replace the string that you need, but that will be longer code that will provoke just one question: `why do you read file by chunks if you don't use them ?`

The shortest way to achieve what you want is:

```
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync('file_name.html', 'utf8')
let replaced = fileContent.replace(/id="wrap"/g, 'dududud')
fs.writeFileSync('file_name.html', replaced)
```

All these functions are `synchronous`, so you don't have to promisify them

Comment: FYI `fileContent` is a Buffer object here so you need a toString() in there somewhere

Comment: FYI `readFileSync` returns a buffer if no encoding is specified, but here it is set to `utf8`, so a string will be returned

Comment: I wouldn't agree - streams properly converted to strings and with some buffering won't give you that issue - I remember a blog post somewhere about searching in streams and basically all you need to do is to use a slice of `needle.length` added from the next buffer and another one of same length from previous buffer. 

I'm sure there's a module for that. :D