# How to read a random line from a .txt file and write it in another .txt file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some data in a .txt file like so:

```
Michael|30
John|23
Eric|34
Dave|20
```

I want to select a random line from that file, then delete the entire line from that file and write it to another.

I have tried different ways but none of them seem to work properly.

So any ideas how to actually do it?

Comment: Generally you can't delete a line from a file (or a character, for that matter) because file systems don't typically support files that contain gaps. What you probably want to do is copy the content EXCEPT for the line to a temporary file. Output the single line you want to to the other file. Then when you're done, delete the original and rename the temporary file with the original file's name.

Comment: I assume you've looked over the [Node File System docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html). It explains how to read and write from files. If so, it is customary to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your specific problem.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483326/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-read-then-write-the-same-file-with-node-js-stre

Comment: _I have tried different ways_. Which ones ?

Comment: Oh my god, I just noticed my spelling mistakes, thanks for correcting my post, that's embarrassing

So this is what I have to delete the first file, but I have no idea how to write it to another...
[link](https://pastebin.com/AWVafN6w)